# MariaDB ran mysql_secure_installation, but seeing remote login attemps in logs

Tags: mariadb, security, remote

I installed MariaDB and ran mysql_secure_installation and answered yes to all questions to remove anonymous user, test DB, remote login, etc.

However, I recently had MariaDB crash and in checking the logs I found numerous login attempts of the form:

> [Warning] IP address '218.60.8.253' could not be resolved: Name or
>   service not known

Is this normal?  To me it indicates that the server is indeed accepting remote connections.

I checked /etc/my.cnf, and did not see the expected `bind-address=127.0.0.1` directive shutting down remote login.  I have added it manually and restarted the server, but now I am wondering if the mysql_secure_installation did what it was supposed to do.

Is there a way to check that mysql_secure_installation ran correctly?

Comment: Something can be "secure" at any of several layers.  "mysql_secure_installation" can't prevent hackers from getting into your machine; it will (hopefully) reject any attempt to access the data or data definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the server would still be accepting remote connections. And yes, it probably did what it was supposed to do. `mysql_secure_installation` doesn't set `bind-address=127.0.0.1` neither in [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_secure_installation/) nor in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-secure-installation.html). It does however allow you to remove root accounts that are accessible from outside of localhost, as you have already done.

If you don't have any database users with host != localhost, then remote login shouldn't be possible. You can of course also block the MariaDB server port in your firewall.